# Solution to store images when the Reactjs client sends images to the server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, image

I tried using base64 to encode the image and save it to MongoDB but its size is big. Website slows down when reloading the website.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the image in the file system and save the path of that image to the database.

Comment: should i use multer or something else ?

Comment: yep, multer is an easy solution